# My php/jquery/ajax design hierarchy isnt working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I currently have a site I built using jquery/php/PDO/mysql.

I use classes for most functions, including database, logins, content, etc...

I am wanting to change my forms over to jquery's ajax calls. But there's where my problems start. With the ajax call, I can't call a php function in the ajax post url. Heres the heirarchy Im using;

`->content.php (form resides in a function named content.)
  ->process.php (post checks and then a call to add content from class)
    ->class.content.php (insert vars into db)`

Once form is submitted, it goes to process.php which contains checks and then a class call to add content.

While this hierarchy seems to be the most used for ajax, it causes path issues. It breaks my db connection, my config connection, etc...

All I really want is to add ajax forms. But I don't want to rewrite my whole site. Any suggestions?

Comment: No idea without looking at the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like process.php was previously included in content.php but now you're trying to submit to it directly. However, process.php was dependant upon the configuration variables, database connection etc. which was included in content.php and accessible by being included within that page.

I think you need to make a new page which includes the same other files and has the same initialisation code as content.php, except it doesn't output the form and instead just includes process.php, then submit to the new page.

Hard to say for sure without code though.